# iPhone app - initial unresponsiveness on iOS 6 on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6

I have an iPhone app that runs fine on iPhones (tested on iOS 6 and iOS 5), and iPads running iOS 5. However, on an iOS 6 iPad, the app is initially unresponsive until resized from 1x to 2x mode (or vice versa), or an orientation change.

This appears to be a bug in the Operating System, since an app isn't supposed to be able to react to changes to the 1x or 2x mode, but it's still baffling. Any ideas?

Comment: You should never start by suspecting a bug in the OS/Compiler/Linker just because things behave strangely. In 99.9% of all cases, the problem is in your own code which is buggy in the first place, reacting wildly depending on the OS/HW platform. ...just saying.

Comment: I agree, which is why it's baffling. It works fine on iPhones running iOS 6 (it's an iOS app), but it is unresponsive on the iPad running iOS 6 until an event that cannot be detected is triggered. It works fine on the other iPad running iOS 5.

Answer (score 9):

I also see this issue on my apps. I found a solution: In the Xcode project -> Targets -> Summary, scroll down to 'Status Bar', check the box for 'Visibility' 'Hide during application launch'. After doing this, the iPhone app works again on **iPad iOS 6**.

You may notice that after the change the status bar is hidden. You can re-enable it in code with:
  [application setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];

Answer (score 1):

PaiGow's fix worked for me, but in the iPad Retina sim with iOS 6, views pinned to the top edge of my (Landscape-only) screen moved up into status bar space and were cropped by the dummy status bar than the iPhone "display" on iPad uses.

Instead, I left "Hide during application launch" UNchecked, but still used the line:

```
[application setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

in my app delegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive` call.

Just making this call to `setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:` is enough to make the app responsive again, in both the sim and on an actual device, and it has no visual side effects that I can see.

I've also tried putting the call in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and it works in the sim; haven't heard back from my beta tester with the iPad yet as to whether it works just as well in hardware.